# how could i check connectivity using cubit?

Tags: flutter, dart, connection, wifi

I need to check the connectivity in every page inside my application using connectivity library,
So i will use a cubit inside the provider. the question is when to close the stream to make it possible to dispose it when the user close the app?

**just like this:**

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
@override
dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  subscription.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Please revisit your question and clarify... basically all of it. We are sitting at the other side of the world with none of the context you have. A question so generic and vague as this is unanswerable. Please post your full code and ask a question in that context. I see no connectivity check, I see no cubit, I have no idea what "subscription" in your program even *is*. So how could I possibly say anything to help you with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

**1. Make sure you have imported  `flutter_bloc` and `connectivity_plus` in your `pubspec.yaml`.**

**2. Create an InternetCubit files:**

- *internet_cubit.dart*
- *internet_state.dart*

**3. internet_state.dart:**

Here we create enum with connection types for our cubit and cubit states:

```dart
part of 'internet_cubit.dart';

enum ConnectionType {
  wifi,
  mobile,
}

@immutable
abstract class InternetState {}

class InternetLoading extends InternetState {}

class InternetConnected extends InternetState {
  final ConnectionType connectionType;

  InternetConnected({@required this.connectionType});
}

class InternetDisconnected extends InternetState {}
```

**4. internet_cubit.dart:**

Cubit depends on connectivity plugin, so we import it and create a stream subscription to be able to react on connection changes.

Also we define two methods `emitInternetConnected` and `emitInternetDisconnected` that will change actual cubit state.

Make sure to dispose of stream subscription properly.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

part 'internet_state.dart';

class InternetCubit extends Cubit<InternetState> {
  final Connectivity connectivity;
  StreamSubscription connectivityStreamSubscription;
  InternetCubit({@required this.connectivity})
      : assert(connectivity != null),
        super(InternetLoading()) {
    connectivityStreamSubscription =
        connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((connectivityResult) {
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        emitInternetConnected(ConnectionType.wifi);
      } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile) {
        emitInternetConnected(ConnectionType.mobile);
      } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        emitInternetDisconnected();
      }
    });
  }

  void emitInternetConnected(ConnectionType _connectionType) =>
      emit(InternetConnected(connectionType: _connectionType));

  void emitInternetDisconnected() => emit(InternetDisconnected());

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    connectivityStreamSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

**5. In your app main file create an instance of `Connectivity` plugin and pass it to your `BlocProvider`. Set up bloc consuming with your needs:**

```dart
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_4/cubit/internet_cubit.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp(connectivity: Connectivity()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final Connectivity connectivity;

  const MyApp({Key key, this.connectivity}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => InternetCubit(connectivity: connectivity),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Connectivity cubit',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Connectivity cubit spotlight'),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                BlocBuilder<InternetCubit, InternetState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is InternetConnected &&
                        state.connectionType == ConnectionType.wifi) {
                      return Text(
                        'Wifi',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 30),
                      );
                    } else if (state is InternetConnected &&
                        state.connectionType == ConnectionType.mobile) {
                      return Text(
                        'Mobile',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow, fontSize: 30),
                      );
                    } else if (state is InternetDisconnected) {
                      return Text(
                        'Disconnected',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 30),
                      );
                    }
                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```