# Check or listen continuously to internet connection/Network Connectivity in dart, flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, connection, connectivity

I have been searching for long to know the best approach to listen to internet connection in flutter/dart app. I think this approach is better for now and it can be of help to some like me who has been searching. I have used many connectivity plugins, but it didn't work. I have equally used data_connection_checker, lookUpAddress etc as suggested by many but to no avail. But below helped.
Use the below plugins to check or listen to Internet Connection / Network Connectivity in dart, flutter app.

[connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus)

[internet_connection_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_connection_checker)

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:internet_connection_checker/internet_connection_checker.dart';

class ConnectionUtil {
  static final ConnectionUtil _singleton = new ConnectionUtil._internal();
  ConnectionUtil._internal();

  static ConnectionUtil getInstance() => _singleton;

  bool hasConnection = false;

  StreamController connectionChangeController = StreamController();

  final Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
  void initialize() {
    _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen(_connectionChange);
  }

  void _connectionChange(ConnectivityResult result) {
    _hasInternetInternetConnection();
  }

  Stream get connectionChange => connectionChangeController.stream;
  Future<bool> _hasInternetInternetConnection() async {
    bool previousConnection = hasConnection;
    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      // this is the different
      if (await InternetConnectionChecker().hasConnection) {
        hasConnection = true;
      } else {
        hasConnection = false;
      }
    } else {
      hasConnection = false;
    }

    if (previousConnection != hasConnection) {
      connectionChangeController.add(hasConnection);
    }
    return hasConnection;
  }
}
```

Implement this code on the stateful widget.....

```
  bool hasInterNetConnection = false;

  @override
  initState() {
    ConnectionUtil connectionStatus = ConnectionUtil.getInstance();
    connectionStatus.initialize();
    connectionStatus.connectionChange.listen(connectionChanged);

    super.initState();
  }

  void connectionChanged(dynamic hasConnection) {
    setState(() {
      hasInterNetConnection = hasConnection;
    });
  }
```

Good luck

Comment: Are we need to close the listen to function or not?

Comment: If I navigate away from the route where I implemented this as described and then return to that route I get an "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to." error. Should there not be some kind of unsubscribe or dispose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had faced a similar problem a few weeks ago. This is a good approach. The `internet_connection_checker` plugin allows one to address issues at the network layer that the `connectivity_plus` plugin cannot address. I have carried out an implementation  of these two plugins using the `bloc` library. For more information and code refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635645/cannot-retrieve-the-status-of-the-internet-connection-when-the-app-is-re-launche) Stackoverflow post and [this](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/2649) Github issue.

Answer (score 0):

Already late answer but still some one looking for check/show internet speed while loading or uploading data.

User this Library - [internet_speed_test: ^1.5.0](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test)

the function used like

```
import 'package:internet_speed_test/internet_speed_test.dart';

  final internetSpeedTest = InternetSpeedTest();

  internetSpeedTest.startDownloadTesting(
     onDone: (double transferRate, SpeedUnit unit) {
        // TODO: Change UI
     },
     onProgress: (double percent, double transferRate, SpeedUnit unit) {
        // TODO: Change UI
     },
     onError: (String errorMessage, String speedTestError) {
        // TODO: Show toast error
     },
   );
```

and

```
internetSpeedTest.startUploadTesting(
     onDone: (double transferRate, SpeedUnit unit) {
       print('the transfer rate $transferRate');
       setState(() {
         // TODO: Change UI
       });
     },
     onProgress: (double percent, double transferRate, SpeedUnit unit) {
       print(
           'the transfer rate $transferRate, the percent $percent');
       setState(() {
         // TODO: Change UI
       });
     },
     onError: (String errorMessage, String speedTestError) {
       // TODO: Show toast error
     },
  );
```

enjoy coding